# Mov seg to ax error in emu8086

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I just installed emu8086 and I get strange error I don't understand on line `mov ax, SEG datahere`. It looks like it doesnt recognize the SEG keyword. Why? The code compiles just fine in TASM+DosBox or in GUI Turbo Assembler.

```
.model small
     ASSUME CS: codehere, DS:datahere, SS:stackhere

datahere segment para public 'DATA'

; data segment goes here

datahere ends   

stackhere segment word stack 'STACK'

     dw 400h dup (00)

stackhere ends

codehere segment para public 'CODE'
     start:

     mov ax, SEG  datahere
     mov ds, ax

     ; code goes here

     ; END
     mov ah, 4ch
     int 21h

codehere ends
     end start
```

Error:

```
wrong parameters: MOV  ax, SEG  datahere
probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var: (ITSELF)
```

Comment: Make sure you copied everything correctly. In particular, you have `datah segment` and also `MOV  ax, SEG  duomenys` ???

Comment: fixed, just typo. I'm 100% sure the code itself works in TASM or GUI Turbo Aseembler. I just deleted the stack park and additional unrequired code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `SEG`. It's only used, if you need the segment of a variable or a label which has normally also an offset. `datahere` is already recognized and handled as a segment address (also in TASM).

Comment: Great answer. And what if I have `num1: db 00` in my data segment and it says that `num1` is undefined then I write `mov byte ptr num1, al`. How to properly define my num1? Seems that emu8086 is very strict to coding.

Comment: @Dancia: `num1 db 00` (without colon). You don't need to "cast" `num1`, if the assembler can recognize the size (with `al` it's recognized as byte).

Comment: For the cosmetic stile i use brackets " mov [num1],al " for to access a memory location. And mostly we have to specify the size of a memory access, if we use an instruction with an immidiate value operand for example.